# Video play status listener in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, video-player

I have a Video control and a button(disabled mode) in my flutter web application.

My requirement

1. The Video player should play without any controls on the video player
2. Once the video is finished playing, It should enable the button.

This is achieved in my mobile application with a listener but I am not able to achieve this in my Web application.

I tried by referring materials available but its failing

Thanks for your help